# How do I add a custom theme feature in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm building a custom theme in Drupal 7 and I'd like to add more "features" to the [list of theme specific settings](http://drupal.org/node/221905).

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way of doing this in the docs. I've found the [guide for how to do it in Drupal 5 and 6](http://drupal.org/node/177868), but it doesn't seem to work for D7 (unless I made a mistake while copying the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is http://drupal.org/update/themes/6/7#theme-settings helpful? There's also the example of the Garland theme, which uses the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` method.

Comment: thank-you-thank-you-thank-you. I'd managed to miss the settings conversion bit in the *wall of text* that is the `d6->d7` conversion page.

Comment: Glad that helped. I added the section from the D6/D7 conversion docs to the first link you had. Though the page is already a bit unwieldy, maybe others will look there first, since maybe they're starting fresh with D7.